# What are the basic properties of the group P63/mmc?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

I can hardly find online information about the group $P63/mmc(O)$. I mean, what is its order, what are the relations between the elements, generating set, etc.?

Any help is appreciated,

Thanks!

Comment: See [here](https://www.sciencedirect.com/topics/chemistry/p63-mmc), or [here](http://img.chem.ucl.ac.uk/sgp/LARGE/194az3.htm), etc.including [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_space_groups) for more references. The order is infinite, because Space groups are always infinite groups.

Comment: Thanks. i have been to these places already. the first link costs money and seem to be about physics, the second one is not clear, can't get any information i wanted from it. wikipedia might have the answers but i've spent so much time there and still didn't get the answers for these basic questions. I was hoping someone who knows could guide me a little further.

Comment: Google "Space groups" in general. This is for free. The order is clear now, I think. Generators and relations are also well-known:) Try a google-search! My first search hit is [this article](http://met.iisc.ernet.in/~lord/webfiles/Nets/spcgps/spcgps.pdf).